# How to calculate waste heat dissipation from a DC-to-DC-to-DC conversion

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, efficiency, linear-regulator

I am wondering how I can calculate the total combined heat dissipation (in watts) by two DC-DC converters in the following scenario;

In my case, I have a project where I have 12 volt DC, which gets stepped down to 5 volts with a DC-DC switching buck converter (LM2596) and then that 5v is converted to 3.3 volts, through a linear regulator  (AMS1117).

The final 3.3 volt load on the linear regulator will be about 0.75 amp.

The 5v buck converter is only powering the linear regulator.

**As I understand it, to calculate the heat dissipation of a switching buck converter, you would go;**

*Output power (Watts) = Voltage * current*

*total input power (Watts) = Output power/efficiency% (per datasheet)*

*Waste heat dissipation (Watts) = Input power – Output power.*

**Whereas for a linear regulator, the waste heat is;**

*Output power (Watts) = Voltage * current*

*efficiency% = Output voltage/input voltage*

*total input power (Watts) = Output power/efficiency%*

*Waste heat dissipation (Watts) = Total input power – Output power*

***However, I'm confused as to how I could calculate the total combined waste heat if you convert DC downwards twice, with 2 different converters?***

The switching buck converter I’m using to get from 12V dc to 5v dc is LM2596, which has an efficiency of around 80% when going from 12V dc to 5v dc. (Datasheet; https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1654906081217&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

The linear regulator to get from 5v to 3.3v is AMS1117 (datasheet; http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf)

***So in summary, how would I calculate the total combined waste heat of the buck converter and linear regulator, if I go from 12V to 5V with the LM2596 buck converter (80% efficiency) and then go from 5v to 3.3v with the AMS1117 linear regulator, with the linear regulator powering a 3.3v 0.75 amp load?***

Thank you!

**[Update]**

I think this may actually be really simple. Is the total output power on the buck converter simply just the total input power of the linear regulator?

So,

***Waste heat linear regulator;***

Output power (Watts) = Voltage * current = 3.3v * 0.75A = 2.48W

efficiency% = Output voltage/input voltage = 3.3v/5v = 66%

total input power (Watts) = Output power/efficiency% = 2.48/0.66 = 3.76W

Waste heat dissipation (Watts) = Total input power – Output power

= 3.76W - 2.48W = 1.27W

***Waste heat buck converter;***

output power (W) = input power of linear regulator = 3.76W

efficiency% = 80%

total input power (Watts) = Output power/efficiency% = 3.76W / 0.8 = 4.7W

Waste heat dissipation (Watts) = Total input power – Output power

= 4.7W - 3.76W = 0.94W

***total heat dissapation of both supplies*** = 1.27W + 0.94W = 2.21W

Comment: check the datasheet for your linear regulator, R2 in fig 1 takes some current to ground, so your efficiency estimate is *slightly* optimistic. In practice, the error is minor at these currents. It might become a significant percentage at lower output currents. Otherwise, without checking your actual numbers, your approach looks OK.

Comment: The 80% efficiency is only provided for 3 A load current. It could be slightly different at 0.75 A. I would guess somewhere between 70% and 90%.

Comment: thanks for the feedback